# How to rotate display output but not touch input

Tags: touchscreen

I recently bought a Tolino Shine. I wanted acces to the underlying Android System, so I opened the device and enabled adb. Now, the display shows everything rotated by 180 degrees. The touch input is still unrotated. It bothers me that input and output are not in sync.

I should mention that there is Android 2.3.3 installed on the device and I successfully rooted the device.

How can I rotate either display output or touch input?

Comment: Are you telling us the screen rotated to 180 degrees just by enabling USB debugging? Did you execute some command which you forgot to mention in question?

Comment: No, the manufacturer disables ADB and any access to other software. I had to physically open the device, extract the SD-card, plug it into my Computer, modify the contents of the SD-card and plug in everything again. I followed [this guide](http://naberius.de/2013/06/26/collected-shiny-adb-and-root-the-fc-easy-way/). But my version number is different then Hecke's, so I assume that broke something.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Ultimate Rotation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) by FaMe IT.

Comment: You should describe this and how it helps with the specific issue OP faces.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed the app but I cannot find an option to turn output and input independently. I only can turn both simultaneously. And this is the lesser problem. Is there some option I have overlooked?